# Should I train at what I want my best to be?

Tags: running, workout-routines, running-training-plan, sprinting

To see results should I train where I want my result to be? For example, on Tuesdays part of my workout is 8 x 100m @ 90% effort. Should I run at my 90%, or what I want my 90% to be? This is something that I am only trying to apply to running for now.

Comment: Where does 90% effort come from? Effort based training would not be tied down to one specific pace but effort is approximately tied to one value of %HRmax.

Comment: How do you measure the effort?

Comment: The 90% is simply from my training plan, based off this www.brianmac.co.uk/longjump/ljplan.htm I measure the effort based on my PR

Comment: If I want to eventually be at world record speed, I probably can't achieve 90% of that, so I'd guess the 90% refers to your current capability/capacity.

Comment: I haven't actually run a competitive 100m in years, because I mainly compete on indoor tracks, but if calculations are correct, it should be somewhere in the 12-13 second range. I train in the 14-15 range, and use the lack of true evidence as my excuse. I am mostly my own coach, because I find that if I want to go far, I must go alone. Basically, should I be pushing harder?

Comment: I would think that training at the recommended 90% of your current max ability will help to improve your max ability, which will reset where 90% is, so, yes, you would lower that time, over time.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in the title. No, dont train at what you want to be able to run at. Do a mile, 12 minute, or 2 mile test run at your best then use this to base what your training should be. Look up Jeff Galloway's magic mile table or use McMillian's calculator to figure out what your goal distance time would be using the test run time. This time is what you should expect to do or better. During training never run more than 60% of your goal distance at this pace. 2-4 weeks out run no more than half of the distance at this pace several times to train at your this pace.

Training at the proper paces will eventually bring you into range of achieving your goal ignoring things that are out of your control.

McMillan has some suggested goal paces you can use and I just paraphrased what he says.